# Symbols in XML causes parsing errors

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am currently dealing with large xml files that will not parse using the XmlDocument Load method due to symbols in field values. For example look at the screen shot from visual studio.

What does the ? in the black diamond mean? Is it a hex character?

[image]

The second part to my question. Is there c# code that I can write that search loads the xml file into a string and find all of these symbols?

```
    <root>
      <record>
        <field>field�field</field>
      </record>
    </root>
```

after doing more research I have discovered there is a "hidden" character. The character is a non breaking space. Is the non breaking space a valid XML character as per the XML specification https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets. The non breaking space has a hex ascii value of xA0.

Char       ::=      #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]  /* any Unicode character, excluding the surrogate blocks, FFFE, and FFFF. */

Comment: which encoding are you using ?

Comment: I believe the diamond symbol represents a non-UTF-8 character,  which would explain why C# can't parse it. I am not sure what encoding it could belong to though.

Comment: That is correct. Is there a way to find and replace all special characters.

Comment: Could this have something to do with file encoding?

Comment: @sowrd299 no, that is the Unicode replacement character, used to replace unmappable characters when trying to read ANSI text using the wrong codepage. The OP didn't explain what "will not parse" means, but there is definitely a conversion error even before the file is read.

Comment: @user3845056 what do you mean "will not parse"? What error is raised? This character appears *only* when reading ANSI text using the wrong codepage. It wouldn't appear if the text really was UTF8. Perhaps you tried to read an ANSI file?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos 7, that makes sense, thank you.

Comment: See updates to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I am able to parse and deserialize the above XML.

Try this:

**Serialization Class**

```
public class root
{
    public record record { get; set; }
}
public class record
{
    public string field { get; set; }
}
```

**C# Code**

```
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            try
            {
                var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.Load("D:\\TestXML.xml");
                // Deserialize the XML
                var Deserializer = DeserializeXml<root>(xmlDoc.DocumentElement.OuterXml);
                //Get number of occurrences of '�'
                int count = Deserializer.record.field.Split('�').Length - 1;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        public static T DeserializeXml<T>(string xml)
        {
            T result;
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (TextReader tr = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                result = (T)ser.Deserialize(tr);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

[image: UnitTest1 IMG Snapshot]

Comment: This will not work as the code will throw and exception on xmlDoc.Load()

Comment: I would not have posted the question if I was not getting an exception on xmlDoc.Load().

Comment: Also I want a way to find all characters that cause the xmlDoc.Load to throw an exception.

Comment: So what is different between the files?

Comment: Nothing. Just use the code I posted and you'll be able to parse through your stated XML.

Comment: `�` is only a representation of an unknown character, it can be one of a large number of characters. Replacing all of them is a lot more, the correct way to handle this would be to use the correct encoding.

Comment: @user3845056 post the *actual* code and that produces the error and the *full* exception as returned by Exception.ToString(). Make sure you aren't trying to read an ANSI file as if it were UTF8, or that you haven't added the "UTF-8" encoding attribute to a file that is *not* UTF-8